# Remove Extra white space at the top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a web page using bootstrap carousel theme. The white space at the top is still visible. I want to remove it. I am providing my carousel CSS file  and my HTML file. I have tried changing the padding and margin but nothing seems to work.
Please help.

```
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}



/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}



/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}



/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}
```

my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/bootstrap/docs/examples/carousel/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/nlog.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/fb.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
  <body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-t
        op" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Resumeeeee !!!</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <!--<li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>-->
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Signup</a></li>
          </ul>

                  <!--<ul class="nav pull-right">-->
                 <!-- <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="float:right">-->

                  <!--</ul>-->

                <!--</ul>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/six.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Stay on the top.</h1>
              <p>Get noticed by your super seniors</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/four.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Get selected</h1>
              <p>we make sure your supersenior recoomends you as fast as possile</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/third.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One thing more for good measure.</h1>
              <p>Get your resume viewed by many other people who are at the top of their level</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->



    <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

    <div class="container marketing">

      <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/face1.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
          <h2>Martin Rodriguez</h2>
          <p>"I got Placed at Amazon .Thanks to Resume"</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/face2.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
          <h2>Tim Dunn</h2>
          <p>"I got Placed at microsoft .Thanks to Resume"</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/face3.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
          <h2>Steve Mccharthy</h2>
          <p>"I use Resume to hire from the abundant fresh talent around the world"</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      </div><!-- /.row -->


      <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">Get Helped <br><span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
          <p class="lead">Super Seniors will help you on your highway to success</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/super.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/try.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
          <p class="lead">Try it for free.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
          <p class="lead">Get Placed At you Dream Company</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/logo.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer>
        <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2014 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
      </footer>

    </div><!-- /.container -->






<!--      sadasdasdasdasd               -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="main">

      <h3>Please Log In</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Facebook</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">Google</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="login-or">
        <hr class="hr-or">
        <span class="span-or">or</span>
      </div>

      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputUsernameEmail" class="abovelogin">Username or email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsernameEmail">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <a class="pull-right" href="#" id="fpassword">Forgot password?</a>
          <label for="inputPassword" class="abovelogin">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox pull-right">
          <label class="abovelogin">
            <input type="checkbox">
            Remember me </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary">
          Log In
        </button>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>




<!--      sadasdasdasdasd               -->








<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="container" id="wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="r" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form" role="form">   <legend>Sign Up</legend>
                    <h4>It's free and always will be.</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name"  />                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name"  />                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Your Email"  /><input type="password" name="password" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password"  /><input type="password" name="confirm_password" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password"  />                    
                    <label id ="bdate">Birth Date</label>                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            <select name="month" class = "form-control input-lg">
<option value="01">Jan</option>
<option value="02">Feb</option>
<option value="03">Mar</option>
<option value="04">Apr</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">Jun</option>
<option value="07">Jul</option>
<option value="08">Aug</option>
<option value="09">Sep</option>
<option value="10">Oct</option>
<option value="11">Nov</option>
<option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            <select name="day" class = "form-control input-lg">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            <select name="year" class = "form-control input-lg">
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <label class="sidetext">Gender : </label>                    <label class="radio-inline" id="rbuttonmale">
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" id=male/>   
                                             Male
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" id="rbuttonfemale">
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" id=female />                        Female
                    </label>
                    <br />
              <span class="help-block">By clicking Create my account, you agree to our Terms and that you have read our Data Use Policy, including our Cookie Use.</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block signup-btn" type="submit">
                        Create my account</button>
            </form>          
          </div>
</div>            
</div>
</div>
</div>



































    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="/Users/amandhapola/Desktop/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>






  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show a working demo of your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: or [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new#) to include bootstrap by default.

Comment: try css reset? `body {margin: 0}`

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689767/random-white-space-in-body-element

Answer (score 2):

Body and .navbar-wrapper .container all have default margins, (typically 8 pixels, note margins collapse when they overlap so you don't get 16 pixels), add this to fix that.

```
body {
   margin:0
   padding: 0 0 40px 0; /* zero padding except 40 pixels on bottom */
}
.navbar-wrapper {
   margin:0;
}
.container {
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

Generally what I do is start off by setting all margins and paddings to zero at the begining and specifying the margins as I need them, leaving nothing to chance.

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

I consider that the safest way to go for what it is worth.